# My first PHP/MySQL db, no output to the webpage?

Tags: php, html, mysql, content-management-system

I'm a noob to PHP/mySQL and I'm enjoying it, but I'm stuck... I'm in the process of developing my first database driven website. I've created the database, the tables... loaded one table in particular with content in an attempt to pull data from it via PHP. If you go to my website live via the browser, there is a navigation system that seems to work but, it's not loading content from the db table. It's just blank content with a nav system that changes the page in the address bar but blank content. I've provided the code along with a image shot of the table in my database I'm trying to GET the data from. The db table i'm getting from is called vls_pages. It is also the table featured in the image. I'm hoping someone can point me to getting this to function correctly. Thank you everyone

index.php CODE:

```
<?php
// Load Setup document:
include
('_config/setup.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrap_overall">



    <div class="nav_main">
        <?php include('_template/nav_main.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="body_header">
        <?php get_page_name($dbc, $pg); ?>
    </div>   

    <div class="content">
        <?php get_page_body($dbc, $pg); ?>    
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <?php include('_template/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

setup.php CODE:

```
<?php
## Setup Document

// host(or location of the database), username, password, database name

        //Variables for connecting to your database.

    //These variable values come from your hosting account.

        $hostname = "***************";
                    $username = "***************";
                    $password = "***************";

        //Connecting to your database

$dbc = @mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unsuccessful.");

        // Check connection
       if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbc))
{
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

       include('_functions/snippets.php');

       if ($_GET['pgname'] == '') {
        $pg = 'home';
           }

       else {
        $pg = $_GET['pgname'];
}

        $page_title = get_page_title($dbc, $pg);

?>
```

snippets.php CODE:

```
<?php

// Snippets; Functions

function get_page_title ($dbc, $pg) {

$query = "SELECT pgtitle FROM vls_pages AND pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$page = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

return $page['pgtitle'];

@mysqli_close($dbc);

}

function get_page_name ($dbc, $pg) {

$query = "SELECT pgname FROM vls_pages WHERE pgname = '$pg' AND pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$page = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo '<h1>'.$page['pgname'].'</h1>';

@mysqli_close($dbc);

}

function get_page_body ($dbc, $pg) {

// the database connection, our query

$query = "SELECT * FROM vls_pages WHERE pgbody = '$pg' AND pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$page = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo '<div class="content">'.$page['pgbody'].'</div>';

@mysqli_close($dbc);

}

?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Stop working on this code until you've learned about them, and how to avoid them. And as a general tip, **NEVER** use the `@` error suppression operator, especially while you're learning. It's the coding equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalal can't hear you alalalalalal".

Comment: For one thing do `$query = "SELECT pgtitle FROM vls_pages WHERE pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1";` not `AND`

Comment: @Barmar [to suppress errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), makes life a whole lot more exciting :)

Comment: That's `lalalalalala` and not `alalalalalal` unless you assign a function to move that last `l` over to the beginning lol @MarcB (just trying to put smile on your face) ;-)

Comment: @spsc_tech: uh, OP **IS** using mysqli. Just using it totally badly.

Comment: sorry, it looked so awful ... need more coffee ...

Comment: Isn't it great when someone "cashes in" ;-) [Sharing the wealth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19501513/1415724)

Comment: Ok, my work is done here.

Answer (score 2):

You're closing the database connection at the end of each function. So after you get the page title, the database connection closes.

Remove this line from the end of every function in setup.php:

```
@mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Then add that line to the end of index.php to close the connection after the page is done processing:

```
<?php
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

This will solve the major issue described in the question. For the sake of completeness, you should also follow the recommendations in the comments area of the question. Specifically, the SQL query in get_page_title() should have "WHERE" instead of "AND", and remove the "@" error suppression, especially while you're learning.

Comment: @Fred -ii-, I upvoted yours and Marc B's comments, to at least share a little of the wealth.

Comment: Thanks. I made a reference to your answer in mine. Sharing the wealth is what it's all about ;-) cheers

Comment: @Aaron Wilson, if you found an answer to be helpful be sure to accept one as the correct answer.

Comment: i will accept an answer when I'm done applying your recommendations. I'm sorry for taking so long to get back to everyone. I work a lot and am transitioning with teaching myself these various web languages and technologies. I appreciate all the good advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in your query, you forgot to keep `where` condition please replace the following code

`$query = "SELECT pgtitle FROM vls_pages AND pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1";`

with

`$query = "SELECT pgtitle FROM vls_pages where pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1";`

Answer (score 0):

As per the `SELECT` syntax in the manual on the [MySQL.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) website.

The syntax is `SELECT select_expr FROM table_references WHERE where_condition equals`

Now, this line is using the `AND` clause:

```
SELECT pgtitle FROM vls_pages AND pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1
```

which should be using the `WHERE` clause, such as:

```
SELECT pgtitle FROM vls_pages WHERE pgstatus = 1 LIMIT 1
```

- Consult [lwitzel's answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19501450/1415724)

**Food for thought:**

Do take the comments into (serious) consideration when it comes to properly sanitizing your inputs.

- The use of PDO is highly recommended - [PDO Tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)